# Why doesn't Java iterator constructor signature has iterator type?

Tags: java, generics, iterator, signature

This may just be a question on the Java iterator constructor's signature layout.

The iterator type must be specified (as an abstract type `T` or something) at the class definition; Thus, why doesn't its corresponding constructor *public GunmenIterator(List list)*  include this `T` iterator type?  Although, typically general type `T` is used in iterator, is this just a design by choice to match other methods?

```
public class GunmenIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

  private List<T> list;
  private Iterator<T> iter;

  public GunmenIterator(List<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.iter = list.iterator();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Iterator<Integer> gunmenIter = new GunmenIterator<Integer>(gunmen);
  }
}
```

As shown above, iterator type `<Integer>` *should* be present in initialization (otherwise, there will be compiler warnings).  However, `<T>` cannot be added to the constructor's signature.

Comment: You don't need <T> in the constructor signature because the constructor is a constructor of the class GunmenIterator<T>. It's thus implicit that its constructor creates an GunmenIterator<T>. Repeating the <T> would be redundant. A constructor always creates an instance of the class it's part of.

Comment: Adding to JBNizet, the `<T>` info is useful not for the instance being built (check "type erasure") but for the definition of the `gunmenIter` variable and to ensure that a valid value is assigned to it.

Comment: @user2864740: I meant constructor -> public GunmenIterator(List<T> list) <- doesn't have T iterator type, whereas initialization should have it

Comment: What started as a comment (because I was not sure if that's what you were asking), turned out into an answer. I reposted it as an answer so that you can mark it as accepted if you feel it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `<T>` in the constructor signature because the constructor is a constructor of the class `GunmenIterator<T>`. It's thus implicit that its constructor creates an `GunmenIterator<T>`.

Repeating the `<T>` would be redundant. A constructor always creates an instance of the class it's part of.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor takes a `List<T>` because it is an `Iterator<T>` *for* a `List<T>`, not an Iterator for an Iterator.

There is no need to specify a *different* generic type parameter as T applies over the *entire* class, including the constructor. Introducing another generic type parameter for the constructor wouldn't work as it would represent a different type.